# How to update total amount for only its parent class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 div's with same class (.items), and each of these div's have 1 select input (.price), text field (.quantity) and text field (.total) (total : 3 input field)

What i want to achieve is when any of the select field `.price` is changed, i want to fetch it's value and then multiply it with the value of `.quantity` and then update the value of `.total`.

The code i have updates all the `.total` of all div's when i change the select input `.price` and i want it to update only its divs `.total` how can i do this?

Hope it makes sense.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var year_amount;
var quantity;
var total;

$(".x_year").change(function(){
    year_amount = this.value;
    $(".x_total").val(year_amount);
});


$(".x_quantity").change(function(){
    quantity = this.value;
    total = year_amount * quantity;

    $('.x_total').val(total);

});

});
</script>




<div class="container">
    <p>
    <select name="year" id="year" class="x_year">
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="222">222</option>
        <option value="452">452</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p><input type="text" name="amount" class="x_amount" id="amount" disabled /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="quantity" class="x_quantity" id="quantity" value="" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="total" class="x_total" id="total" value="" disabled /></p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <p>
    <select name="year" id="year" class="x_year">
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="222">222</option>
        <option value="452">452</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p><input type="text" name="amount" class="x_amount" id="amount" disabled /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="quantity" class="x_quantity" id="quantity" value="" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="total" class="x_total" id="total" value="" disabled /></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your existing HTML and javascript so we can see what you already have and offer more specific advice than coding everything from scratch.

Comment: Hello, just updated the question, please check it out..

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to update your description to match the actual class names in your code. (E.g., "container" rather than "items".)

Comment: Have a look at jQuery's documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this:

```
$(".x_year, .x_quantity").change(function(){
    $(this).closest(".container").find(".x_total").val(this.value);
});
```

This finds the parent `.container` object from what was changed, then finds the `.x_total` object in that container and sets its value.  This single block of JS will work for both x_year and x_quantity.  You could make it even simple by giving both of those objects the same class say `x_autoTotal` (remember, you can have multiple classes on an object) and then using this code:

```
$(".x_autoTotal").change(function(){
    $(this).closest(".container").find(".x_total").val(this.value);
});
```